# Aligning neighbouring paths and “connecting” anchors in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustration, isometric

I am working on isometric design that will be printed on the 1000mm x 2000mm Roll Up. Design includes lots of similar paths that should be perfectly aligned and create isometric 3d scene (image 1.)

[image]

I made diagonal guides (30° and - 30°) in order to create paths and aligned them together. It worked fine until I find out that some paths were not aligned as I wished and when zoom in the scene white gaps can been seen. Each path was created from original one (Alt key - Select the path) moved and aligned manually to the next neighbour.

[image]

However, now I am trying to find the best solution to adjust them and align perfectly without too much manual tweaking. Is there any way to automate the process and connect neighbouring anchors?  I know there is a function in most 3D software named “connect vertices”, but is there something similar in Illustrator?

I am using Illustrator CS5 and CS6.

Thank you.

Comment: Nice picture i really like it. **Tip**: Do not accept your posts so fast wait if theres somebody with a better answer first. This gets you more views and possibly better answers (not my one its more of a how to do this in future kind of thing).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I won't directly answer the question, I will, instead suggest an alternate workflow. The benefit of this workflow is that it is guaranteed that you will not get this problem.

1. First build a isometric grid. Make vertical lines and rotate the field 2 times with 120 degree offset. **Tip:** If you make the lines uncolored then you can just directly color the image.

[image: Isometric grid]

2. Then use the shape builder tool to make your shapes. **TIP**: When in shape builder tool you can assign colors to the fill and stroke, before dragging. That style will be put on the shape.

[image: Screen capture]

**Image 2**: Timelapse of building with shape builder.

Now you are guaranteed never to hit and miss. Working speed is also most likely *much* faster.

Comment: Great tip Joojaa. That looks a lot faster than the OPs original workflow.

Comment: @Dom i am circumventing the fact that one can not make a custom noncartesian snapping grid in Illustrator. Using guides is ofyen a hit and miss kind of thing. And the API does not provide tools for this kind of stuff, without reimplementing line and pen tool.

Answer (score 8):

My way to align/join etc multiple points is as follows:

Press "A" and choose the points in question -

[image]

Now, right click and choose Average->Both:

[image]

+

[image]

The result:

[image]

gif:

[image]

Comment: In addition to this... switching to `Outline Mode` often makes click-dragging to select multiple anchors **much** easier.

Comment: @Scott I've thought to mention command+Y but thought the ts knows about it...