# how do I create this type of grid in illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, grids

I'm trying to create a logo grid and I would like to know how I can achieve something such as the image below in illustrator

[image]

Comment: Somwhat related (even the anwer to your question is there) [aligning-neighbouring-paths-and-connecting-anchors-in-illustrator](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/57262/aligning-neighbouring-paths-and-connecting-anchors-in-illustrator/57267#57267).

Answer (score 3):

1. Create a square that has only a stroke.
2. Go to **Object>Path>Split into grid**
3. Separate into and even amount of rows and columns (I did 8 and 8)and lock the image
   [image]
4. Create a new square on top of it with the exact same size and split it to the same amount but **only to rows** (I did 8 rows)
5. With the direct selection tool grab all of the points on the right side and drag them to the next 2 points on the background image.
   [image]
6. Do the same on the left side downwards..
   [image]
7. Copt this square, paste in front **(cmnd+f)** and go to **OObject>trasnform>reflect>vertical**
8. And you'll have your grid, all you are left to do is unlock the background image:
   [image]