# Unable to snap guide or the the vertical line to the intersecting point

Tags: adobe-illustrator, alignment, guides

[image: Unable to snap guide or the vertical line to the intersecting point]

Hello,

I'm trying to create an Isometric Grid in Adobe Illustrator CS6. Everything with regards to snapping to point was fine till yesterday (although never tried creating an isometric grid before). Based on a video tutorial, I changed the "Keyboard Increment" to 0.125 for create multiple lines (as part of tutorials). I think this is where weird stuff started. Now as it shows in the image, the guide does not snap to the intersecting point and neither does the vertical line.

I reset the keyboard increment value to original one, which is 0.0137 inch.

My perpetual settings are:
a. Snap to Point & Smart Guides are enabled.
b. Snap to Grid: Disabled. (Grid is hidden I don't use it)

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Smart guides aren't great to begin with and they're even worse with paths and intersections (they seem to be better with points).

If they aren't snapping accurately enough for you, enable outline mode (<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd>), zoom in as far as you can and try again.

[image: Smart Guide Intersection Snapping]

Its worth opening the transform panel (**Window → Transform**) first and making sure that "Align to Pixel Grid" isn't checked as that could be causing problems.

---

Not directly related to snapping but you can find methods for creating isometric grids in Illustrator here:

- [Generating isometric grids in Illustrator CC](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/73104/52050)

Comment: Thanks @Cai, it worked. Turns out "Align to Pixel Grid" was checked. I had to simply uncheck it.