# Illustrator: Isometric Grid with coding

Tags: adobe-illustrator, isometric

When I used to go to college, I used to had a Graphic Design teacher who made an isometric grid using code. He had made the grid so that anyone who downloaded the template just jump straight in to the file, pick a triangle to start colouring in. However, on most of the tutorials that I have found online, it looks like you have to use the pen tool to make a shape around the triangle you want, then colour it. So, my question is, would anyone know how to make what my teacher made? Thanks.

Comment: Read: [this](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/73104/generating-isometric-grids-in-illustrator-cc/) and [this](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/57262/aligning-neighbouring-paths-and-connecting-anchors-in-illustrator/57267#57267) If you still need a generator for it after that then let me know. (but yeah you can record CAI's answer so no nee dto code it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need a script for this, although it might help for making a grid from scratch.

Alternatively, you can easily find isometric grid templates online, like [this one here](http://taylorhokanson.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/isometric_grid_30.AI_.zip)

1. Select the grid and click *Object > Clipping Mask > Release*
2. Select all, and click *Object > Live Paint > Make*

At this point you could save the file again, and use it as your new template, already setup as a Live Paint isometric grid.

3. Fill the cells using the Live Paint Bucket Tool.

[image]

If you want to remove the grid, Expand the Live Paint object, and ungroup. Select the grid and delete it.  When you save your artwork, make sure you don't overwrite the template file - give it a new file name instead.

[image]