# Illustrator Isometric scaling

Tags: adobe-illustrator, isometric

I created a grid and started my design/illustration on it.

Deep in the project I realize that some object are supposed to be bigger in size.
So first thought was to scale it up.

The problem is that I can't scale it on grid. It just won't fit anymore.

Any ideas on how I can get this done without having to do it all over again?

This is the original:
[image: This is the "original"]

And this is after scaling:
[image]

You can see at the right side that it isn't on grid anymore. No matter how far I scale it just won't fit.

Comment: Could you possibly include (a) screenshot(s) to better understand what you mean?

Comment: Agree with WELZ..  If you can make an [edit] with screenshots and how your layers are written someone might know of a suggestion.  To mind, I think of scripting this.

Comment: Sorry. Please see my updated question!

Comment: Are you trying to make it taller, wider or just overall larger?

Comment: Overall larger. So scaling proportional on the grid.

Comment: With that drawing you will never be able to both scale proportionally *and* follow the grid, *unless* you scale by a whole number larger than 1 (2 times is minimum). There are lengths that are only 1 cell wide. They have to be scaled at least 200% so they align to the *next* grid line and becomes 2 cells wide. So if you want to scale to less than 200%, you will have to change the proportions.

Comment: There is an alternative to scaling so it hits the grid. You can just learn to draw isometric without a grid. Its no more work and it does not have this shortcoming

Comment: @joojaa How is one to go about that?

Comment: @Interactive that would be a great separate question. There are actually many different approaches for this. But all fo them too long to be descibed in a comment. But yeah just using numeric input works well.

Comment: @joojaa. Okay fair enough. See my question coming up then.... Looking forward to your answer

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You would have to do each side manually (especially if trying to make it follow the grid).

What you do is, use the *Direct Selection Tool* (<kbd>A</kbd>) and select all the points that would have to move in that specific direction and then move **just** those points (it's a bit hard to explain, so I've included a screen capture)

[image: GIF showing the proccess]

You see how I selected all the anchor points that would need to move up, and then dragged it up. Followed same approach for sides.

---

I've made circles and arrows on what I **think** which Anchor points need to move where in your case etc. [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0X0A.png)

Comment: Ugh... That was what I was afraid of. Unfortunately that is gonna be some night work. Thanks for the excellent answer tho' *thumbs up*

Comment: offtopic: how did you get the awesome grid in your first example?

Comment: @spiral I made it myself (don't remember the *exact* details), though I can't seem to locate it. I will keep you posted.

Comment: @spiral I followed joojaa's (not too clear) tutorial [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/57267/63979) and then had to fix it up manually... read from [this chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/41905629)... once I had that I made the stroke slightly thicker, transparent and with dashed lines - then I put it on a locked layer on top of the artwork (so I don't accidentally touch it).... [here's the .ai file](https://nofile.io/f/9EC8zqS7rYd/Isometric+Grid.ai)

Comment: thank you! I dont know hoe I never thought of a dashed isometric grid, but I ended up generating my own with the awesometric actions: https://gumroad.com/l/lDhzV And great tip about using shape builder!

Comment: @spiral thanks, I already had those actions. ([see around this chat message](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/41407009#41407009)) and I use them, but in this case, it made more sense to have a grid -sorta.

Comment: ah, just meant that set has an action that generates a grid