# The true/right isometric?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustration, grids, isometric

i started learning how to create isometric illustrations.
The first step is the isometric grid to work better.

Is there a standard/right/true way? I found different tutorials and was a bit confused because i thought there's mathematically just one true way.

Source 1: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fZ14PgMkFRQ

> **Top**
>
> - Scale:  Horizontal: 82%   Vertical: 70,5%
> - Shear: 30°
> - Rotate: -30°
>
> **Left**
>
> - Scale:  Horizontal: 82%   Vertical: 70,5%
> - Shear: -30°
> - Rotate: -30°
>
> **Right**
>
> - Scale:  Horizontal: 82%   Vertical: 70,5%
> - Shear: 30°
> - Rotate: 30°

Source 2:
https://medium.muz.li/creating-isometric-illustrations-made-simple-with-the-geometric-technique-1a58bb2bb41e

> **Top**
>
> - Rotate: 45°
> - Scale: Horizontal: 100%  Vertical: 57,7350%
>
> **Left**
>
> - Rotate: 45°
> - Scale: Horizontal: 100%  Vertical: 57,7350%
> - Rotate: 60°
>
> **Right**
>
> - Rotate: 45°
> - Scale: Horizontal: 100%  Vertical: 57,7350%
> - Rotate: -60°

Comment: I assume bend is skew. Anyway, you can decompose a matrix in many ways. Personally i use scale, skew, rotate as my decomposition (although if you look at the first hit on SSR method google theres a typo in the scale) . Anyway just rotate a line by 120 degrees for a reference isometric basis to test against. Anyway i recommend that you do NOT use a isometric grid, but learn to do this by numbers and by finding intersection. See https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/105148/isometric-with-or-without-a-grid-in-illustrator/105243#105243

Comment: There *is* just one correct way: the angle between the 3 axes must be 120 degrees. But several ways to achieve that. Read [Wikipedia article on 3D projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection). Pay special attention to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection#/media/File:Graphical_projection_comparison.png) image.

Comment: @Wolff well you could use a rotated isometric axis aswell.

Comment: @joojaa, but must the angle between the 3 axes not always be 120 degrees in order to be called isometric?

Comment: @Wolff well sort of. But you dont have to use thoe 3 axes you could rotate the ground plane for instance. It would still technically be isometric. You would lose out of the primary benefit but still. See the boxcrate image in my isometric shadow post.

Comment: @joojaa Thanks for your comments. I understood there are more than one way to achieve an isometric view. But are the results always the same or are there also different results?

Comment: Also @Wolff for my comment

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A "strict" isometric grid would be

360°/3 = 120°

So we start with an axis at 0°, another at 120°, and another at 240°.

[image]

But we do need a vertical axis, not a purely horizontal one, so let's rotate all our grid 90° so we have now

- 120°+90°=210°
- 240°+90°=330°
- 0°+90°=90°

[image]

A common color coding of the axis is Red for X, Green for Y, and blue for Z Making Z the height. You can invert X and Y. That is why I left the Z or 90° to the last.

So a cube will look like this. The outer lines of the cube would be a perfect hexagon.

[image]

You could explore different angles for stylistic reasons. This could be some kind of pseudo isometric. The camera or point of view would look as if it is lower with respect to the ground for example.

[image]

**Pixel Isometric**

A specific case is an adaptation for pixel art.

I am superimposing a square grid simulating pixels. You can see that it can be optimized.

[image]

The first one is the red and green axis, (X and Y) where we can move it up a bit so a diagonal can cross every two squares on a vertex. (the old axis are dim color)

The second adaptation is height. We can modify a bit the heights so it fits on the grid. (The old top of the cube is on magenta)

[image]

Here is the result with the vertices aligned with the "pixels"

[image]

---

**The new angles**

To find the exact angle we need to do some math. We have a triangle and the trigonometric relation we have is tan because we have the values of the sides of the triangle u and v (I am not using x and y here so I am not confusing about the name of the axis)

[image]

Using an online triangle calculator https://www.calculator.net/triangle-calculator.html?vc=&vx=&vy=1&va=&vz=2&vb=90&angleunits=d&x=59&y=13 we can see that the angle a is 26.56505118°.

[image]

Adding that angle to 180° to get the red axis is 206.5°, and subtracting from 360° to get the green axis is 333.5° sort of...

It is easier just using the squares.

---

I am sure there are other methods to get some other nice isometric looks for pixel art. I like the results of the method I described here.

The only "true" angles are the first on the explanation. The adaptation I made for pixel art or the ones described on your links are different methods to facilitate the drawing of pixel art. It is more subjective to say which one is "correct". Probably the answer is "the one that you like the most".

---

**Some other pixel art options**

The previous grid of 2x1 pixels can be changed, giving different camera angles. Here are some examples using 3x1 and 4x1 grids.

Here are the resulting angles (rounded numbers):

2x1 grid

180+26= **206°**

360-26= **334°**
[image]

3x1 grid

180+18= **198°**

360-18= **342°**
[image]

4x1 gid

180+14= **194°**

360-14= **346°**
[image]

---

The closest one to true isometric is the 2x1 grid, but probably other proportions are more pleasing.

One last thing is that you need to adjust the "height" so it looks proportional to this axis.

Comment: Pseudo isometric = axonometric. But there is a special case and that is the pixel isometric that us tweaked so it fits the pixel grid better.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCovA.png

Comment: I will add that info on the main answer :)

Comment: yes please do that

Comment: According to the edition, I made the angles of the pixel art would not be 198 and 339. Probably they have different logic. :)

Comment: @joojaa, actually the "pseudo isometric" view where two of the three angles are the same would be called *dimetric*. Both *isometric* and *dimetric* are *axonometric* projections. [Wikipedia source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection#/media/File:Graphical_projection_comparison.png)

Comment: I am wondering if there are some standardized dimetric angles. 

Comment: @Wolff the name is generallt reserved for one with specific set of angles. Though your right it would be dimetric in other cases too but we dont call them that. Ltherwise all orthographic views would be trimetric.

Comment: @Rafael depends a bit how you measure the line. In pixel graphics you also have the problem how the lines come together as the join with shared vertical is a bit peculiar because you have a width of 2 joining a width of 1.  Note the angle is measured usually from the centre of the line not the end.

Comment: @joojaa I think I'm seeing my problem. I'll review that.

Comment: @joojaa, I see ... so the Wikipedia article is a bit inaccurate? It also call another set of degrees *dimetric* [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection#/media/File:Axonometric_projections.png).

Comment: @Wolff its technically OK. Like if i has a 15 degree around up rotated isometric is still technically isometric nobody just calls it that. Everybody assumes i use axis aligned objects. Thats why generally.

Comment: @joojaa I still can not figure out where do the angles on the image you posted 198 & 339 come from.

Comment: @Rafael your measuring corner of pixel in horizontal and center in vertical. A pixel is obviously center in both directions. Then there is the fact that on the inner corner you have 3 pixels abreast  to retain symmetry.so the actual reported angle is always a bit off

Comment: Looks like you are brilliant in Maths too :P

Comment: @joojaa I ditched the "line thickness" part totally. And yes. The 3x1 grid is the one you posted.

Comment: @Rafael no its not you measure from corner of pixels i measure from centers. Center of two pixels by two pixels is offcourse a 1 pixel shorter than corner to opposite corner.