In 26.6 degree isometric illustrations, is it customary to have Z-axis be scaled exactly the same as Y- and X-axis?
Sometimes different isometric camera angles produce uneven scaling on different axes - for example a camera that's pointing almost straight down will have a very short rendered z-axis edge on a unit cube compared to x-axis and y-axis edges.
It's my understanding that in 30degree isometric images, all axes are rendered equal - is it customary to also render them equal in 26.6?

if they arent equal then its not isometric but dimetric, or trimetric. ISO means the same. So words that start with iso in science cases mean the same. Like for example  isotropic, which means same value when measured in different directions. But yes only main axes of isometric are same.

Take a look at this: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/145390/the-true-right-isometric/145394#145394
