# Segmented isometric grid

Tags: adobe-illustrator, grids, isometric

I am a beginner when using Adobe Illustrator so I have been searching the web for answers and tips. I came across this [thread](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/105148/isometric-with-or-without-a-grid-in-illustrator?newreg=17fe321938d4480ba314456d3cd06501) about Isometric design using a grid and someone mentioned something about using an isometric segmented grid. How would I set up a segmented grid?

Comment: @joojaa explains the grid creation [**HERE**](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/57262/aligning-neighbouring-paths-and-connecting-anchors-in-illustrator/57267#57267) which he also links to in the question you linked to. Simply follow the link.

Comment: I read that post too. But he doesn't explain how to create a segmented grid. I have been trying to use the stroke panel and adjust dashes and gaps to make the segments align, no luck so far. Ill keep trying

Comment: @IsionIndustries are you talking about what I used in [this answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/105052/63979)?

Comment: I have just drawn one square then copied that.

Comment: @joojaa, it sounds like the OP is struggling with the *"Make vertical lines and rotate the field 2 times with 120 degree offset"* part. Maybe you could make a gif of that? I might do it later if I have the time.

Comment: @WELZ precisely! I am looking to make a segmented grid like that.

Comment: @Wolff Im not struggling with that. Im struggling with making those vertical lines as segments that align properly when rotated just like in the thread that WELZ linked in his answer yesterday.

Comment: @IsionIndustries check out the comments under my post, you may also want to check [this link](https://gumroad.com/l/lDhzV). Basically, I just made the grid and applied a dashed stroke with lower opacity and placed in on a locked layer above my artwork layers.

Comment: @WELZ everytime I add a dashed stroke to the grid then all the dashes dont align up. What is the dash size and dash gap size you set to the stroke?

Comment: @IsionIndustries I'm not actually sure, you can try selecting all the paths and grouping them and then applying a new stroke through the appearance panel (dropdown > new stroke) this should make then continuous.

Comment: If you send me an email (check my profile), I can send you my file.

Comment: Oh I don't think I tried that yet. Hopefully that works. Thank you for some of your advice

Comment: @WELZ what is your email?

Comment: @IsionIndustries it's in [my profile](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users/63979/welz?tab=profile).

Comment: Ill send you a photo of what happens to my isometric grid when I add segments to it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those who are still wondering, here's an [Isometric Grid Template](https://github.com/WELZ-gh/Drafts/raw/master/Saved/IllustratorFiles/IsometricGridTemplate.ait) I made with the grid overlaying an artwork layer.

[image: sample image]

You are free to download and use as desired.

---

I made a bunch of triangles laid out, then applied a thin dashed stroke at a lower opacity on a locked layer above the artwork.