# How to make 3d objects in illustrator with just a stroke

Tags: adobe-illustrator, 3d

I'm trying to make isometric figures in illustrator, but drawing themselves are a really hard job to do just by the eye. For example I want a "T" drawn shape to be like the right one (I made this myself just so I could  show you what I wanted to create), but when I make this a "3D object" I get the left figure, is there any way you can get just the strokes on the shape? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Actually, drawing yourself is probably less work than extruding it. But here is a [trick](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/57262/aligning-neighbouring-paths-and-connecting-anchors-in-illustrator/57267#57267) that might make you even faster. Although i think drawing to a grid is not really worth it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a T with a color fill and no stroke:

[image]

Apply the 3D **Extrude & Bevel** effect with **Wireframe** as a surface:

[image: Extrude & Bevel]

- Menu **Object** > **Expand Appearance**
- Menu **Object** > **Clipping Mask** > **Edit Contents** > Delete
- Pres <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> Mac or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> Win
- Select the T shape
- Pres <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> Mac or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> Win
- Apply a stroke width and a color
- Select the interior shapes with the **Direct Selection Tool** and delete
  them

[image: 3DT]

- Select each shape, fill them and send it back or front to get the final T

[image: Final T]

Comment: Thank you so much, exactly what I needed. Really appreciate it. I think it's kinda stupid how they make it so complex, but luckily there's a way to do it! Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

You *can* leave the object as merely a stroke. Just click the `More Options` Button in the **3D Effect Dialog Window** and change the `Shading Color` to **none** (or something other than the default black).

[image]

Leaving the base object as only a stroked path, it allows you to alter the *stroke weight* in order to change the thickness of the front face on the 3D object. The only difference in the below image is the stroke weight on the object.

[image]

Or change the stroke *color* to alter the object's color:

[image]